# HDDs are displayed with 115.5 PiB Capacity after reboot

Tags: linux, hard-drive, partitioning, gpt

I'm running OpenMediaVault on a raspberry pi and added 3 new 4TB HDDs to the system. After a reboot all drives are displayed with 115.5PiB capacity and matching sector counts (253879390758563) - not just in OMV but in general.

dmesg shows this:

```
[   11.917746] GPT:Primary header thinks Alt. header is not at the end of the disk.
[   11.917771] GPT:7814037167 != 253879390758629
[   11.917788] GPT:Alternate GPT header not at the end of the disk.
[   11.917805] GPT:7814037167 != 253879390758629
[   11.917820] GPT: Use GNU Parted to correct GPT errors.
[   11.917887]  sda: sda1
[   11.924305] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Attached SCSI disk
[   11.924996] GPT:Primary header thinks Alt. header is not at the end of the disk.
[   11.925018] GPT:7814037167 != 253879390758629
[   11.925033] GPT:Alternate GPT header not at the end of the disk.
[   11.925055] GPT:7814037167 != 253879390758629
[   11.925072] GPT: Use GNU Parted to correct GPT errors.
[   11.925131]  sdb: sdb1
```

I tried to fix the problem with fdisk and parted (with sdb, since there is no data), but the tools cannot write to the drives (probably because of the wrong sector count?)
`fdisk: failed to write disklabel: Input/output error`
parted: `Input/output error during write on /dev/sdb`

SMART scans are passing and I can still access all the data stored on sda1

Basically I have 2 Questions:

- What happened and how can I prevent this?
- How can I fix this mess?

Edit(s):

- Drives are connected via a SATA case which uses USB 3.0 to connect to the pi

Comment: How are you connecting the HDDs to the Pi? (Did they gain SATA ports, or are you using a USB adapter?)

Comment: I bought a 5 Bay SATA case which connects to the pi via USB3.0

Comment: Have you tested with a different one? Converting SATA to USB (ATA to SCSI) involves quite a bit of protocol translation.

Comment: I originally had another SATA Hat for the pi but that just wasn't  working properly, sent it back, got the new case and drives and until the reboot everything was working just fine. I don't have another SATA/USB connector

Comment: Do the HDDs use emulated sectors of 512 bytes or 4k native sectors? Some USB SATA connectors have problems with 4KN HDDs...

Comment: fdisk: "Remaining 253879390758629 unallocated 512-byte sectors". But according to the specs from the shop "4KB with emulation (512e)".

If the Connector has problems with those sectors, wouldn't it show from the beginning? I successfully initialized, partitioned and used sda(1), problems started only after the reboot